# Catching assert() with side effects

Tags: c, gcc, assert

We have several moderately sized C code bases that receive commits from developers with a variety of experience levels. Some of the less disciplined programmers commit `assert()` statements with side effects that cause bugs with assertions disabled. E.g.

```
assert(function_that_should_always_be_called());
```

We already use our own `assert()` implementation, but evaluating the expression with `NDEBUG` defined would cause unacceptable performance degradations. Is there a GCC extension or flag we can pass that will trigger compile time warnings/errors for these? With simple enough control flow it should be possible for GCC to determine that you are only calling pure functions.

Comment: No, GCC doesn't check to see whether functions have side effects.

Comment: Perhaps require code review before commit.

Comment: To clarify my question, we do not have the resources to perform manual code review on some of these repositories. For our high priority ones, we do code review. I was looking for something automated that would save us having to knock back commits for these trivial mistakes.

Comment: I don't buy arguments about "not having resources".  You're *saving* time (and sanity) by catching bugs early.  It's not about reviewing existing code, it's about reviewing *changes* before they get committed.

Comment: s/not having resources/manager says no/

Comment: If you asked a coworker to look over a diff before you submit, your manager would object?  You should find a new place to work.

Comment: @Matthew You, not your manager, asserted that you do not have the resources. Don't blame your manager for you making a bad argument.

Comment: I just found a way to make all of my programs pass testing with assertions turned off! `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { assert(real_main(argc, argv)); return 0; }`

Comment: Sigh. We can do code review when necessary, but it would be nice to catch coding errors made by newcomers without manual review. I was simply asking if a feature existed, not for a critique of workplace practices and trolling.

Comment: You're the one trolling here.

Comment: If that is really important to you, you might consider customizing [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) for such purposes.

Answer (score 25):

Despite the many unhelpful non-answers this question has received, I think it has a lot of merit in a context of a legacy code base.

Imagine that many assertions have been accumulated over the years, but because there wasn't a habit of building/testing with NDEBUG, some side-effects have trickled into the assertions and now you don't dare to disable the assertions anymore.

You may turn on NDEBUG and detect some test failures in your test suite, but it is totally not straightforward to link a test failure to the 'effectful' assertion because it may be very far from the point where you detect the failure. And even a test suite with good coverage cannot be trusted to be complete.

You may conduct a code review of all assertions in the code, but this is potentially a lot of work and prone to human error. It would be much better if some static analysis can already eliminate all assertions where it can *prove* that no side-effects appear and you only have to investigate those cases where their absence is not guaranteed.

Here is how you can use the optimizer of your compiler to conduct such a static analysis. Suppose that you organize to replace the definition of the `assert` macro by:

```
extern int not_supposed_to_survive;
#define assert(expr) ((void)(not_supposed_to_survive || (expr)))
```

If `expr` has any side-effect, the execution of the effect is conditional on the value of global variable `not_supposed_to_survive`. But if `expr` does not to have any side-effect, the value of the global variable does not matter (note that the `expr` result is discarded). **A good optimizer knows this and will eliminate the load of global variable `not_supposed_to_survive`**, hence the name of the variable.

If our program does not contain a definition of the symbol `not_supposed_to_survive`, we will get a link error when the load is not eliminated and we can use this to detect a potentially effectful assertion.

E.g. with gcc 4.8:

```
int g;

int foo() { return ++g; }

int main() {
    assert(foo());
    return 0;
}

gcc -O2 assert_effect.c
/tmp/ccunynya.o: In function `main':
assert_effect.c:(.text.startup+0x2): undefined reference to `not_supposed_to_survive'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The compiler helped me find a dubious assertion! On the other hand, if I replace `++g` by `g+1`, the link error disappears and I don't have to investigate. Indeed, that assertion is guaranteed harmless.

Of course, the concept of provably side-effect free is limited by what the optimizer "can see". For a more precise analysis, I would recommend using link-time optimization (`gcc -flto`) to analyze across compilation units.

As a slight usability improvement, it's possible on GCC 4.4 and higher to obtain a human-readable error message on compile time (instead of link time) using the `error` function attribute. Since this attribute works only on functions and not on variables, we additionally need to tell GCC that it's a pure function, which means that the function itself will have no side effects. This ensures that calls to the function can safely be dropped if the return value is not relevant.

```
extern int not_supposed_to_survive() __attribute__((pure)) __attribute__((error("assert() cannot be proven to have no side effects")));
#define assert(expr) do { (void)(not_supposed_to_survive() || (expr)); } while(0)
```

**Update:** I applied the simple variant with the global variable on a real life C++ code base using gcc 5.3. To use link-time optimization, you essentially use `gcc -flto -g` as the compiler/linker (the `-g` option on compiler/linker to get a line reference on link errors) and `gcc-ar` and `gcc-ranlib` as the archiver/indexer for any static libraries.

This setup could tremendously reduce the number of assertions I had to investigate. With minimal manpower I was able to get the assertions clean. The false positives that I still had to turn down manually were due to:

- Virtual function calls
- Non-trivial loops/recursions (where the optimizer can not prove they are finite)

Additionally, I would also get some assertions that indeed contained side-effects, but they are harmless or not significant, such as:

- Functions containing logging statements
- Functions that cache their result(s)

Comment: I'm afraid this will not work as long as there are any memory accesses inside `assert()` e.g. `void foo(int *p) { assert(p[0] > 0); }` as compiler will not be able to remove the guarding condition.

Comment: @yugr Sure it works, the compiler can optimize your `foo` to an empty function: https://godbolt.org/z/e69xwZ

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure whether it would be enough for the application you have described, but cppcheck looks for "assertWithSideEffect"s:
http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/devinfo/doxyoutput/checkassert_8cpp_source.html

Here is what compile-time message looks like:
[assertWithSideEffect] myFile.cpp:42: warning: Non-pure function: 'myFunction' is called inside assert statement. Assert statements are removed from release builds so the code inside assert statement is not executed. If the code is needed also in release builds, this is a bug.

"Cppcheck is a static analysis tool for C/C++ code. Unlike C/C++ compilers and many other analysis tools it does not detect syntax errors in the code. Cppcheck primarily detects the types of bugs that the compilers normally do not detect. The goal is to detect only real errors in the code (i.e. have zero false positives)."
http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

> With simple enough control flow it should be possible for GCC to determine that you are only calling pure functions.

And if it's not a simple enough control flow how will it know if it's pure or not?

---

Something like this is likely your best bet:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define assert(s) do { (s); } while(false)
#else
// ...
#endif
```

Several expressions would be compiled out, including functions with `__attribute__((pure))`.

The most logical solution would be to just review your code and fix mistakes though.

Comment: Agreed - for the correct uses of `assert()`, where the expression has no side-effects - the compiler will be able to elide the code as long as you have optimisation enabled.  A cast to `(void)` is likely to also be useful here, since it may stop the compiler from warning about a statement with no side-effects.

Comment: Obviously more complicated control flow and things like recursion can turn this into the halting problem, but most assertions are relatively simple. I was envisaging some check with a timeout or maximum call depth limit. As for the suggestion, as I said in the question I specifically do not want all assertions evaluated when NDEBUG is defined.

Comment: @Matthew "I was envisaging some check with a timeout or maximum call depth limit." -- what the heck does that have to do with a compile-time check for non-pure functions? You're making no sense at all in your desperation for a GCC feature that a moment's reflection ... or a perusal of the manual ... makes obvious does not exist.

Comment: The main problem with this solution is that it doesn't catch bugs, but fixes them. `assert` with side effects is a very bad practice. The question was how to make `assert` catch this, not how to make it work. Also, this could severely degrade performance, is something like `assert(check_data_structures())` is done.

Comment: " As for the suggestion, as I said in the question I specifically do not want all assertions evaluated when NDEBUG is defined. " -- You completely missed the point. Read the sentence starting "Several expressions ..." and try to understand it.

Comment: @JimBalter I was talking about static analysis, which GCC does in a limited form already. I would argue that the GCC manual, while not describing how this could be accomplished, also does not make it clear that this is not possible; in the same way that the pre-processor manual doesn't explain every trick you can do with it. I understand the "several expressions..." comment, but the compiler does not optimise away all these expressions (yes, I have checked) and some of them are in hot paths which are already bottlenecks.

Comment: @Matthew I'm sure you can argue a lot of things. The GCC manual also doesn't say that it can't cure cancer and bring world peace ...

Comment: @Matthew " the compiler does not optimise away all these expressions" -- another way to say that is "Several (as opposed to all) expressions would be compiled out". Again, you miss the point. In fact, that GCC does not elide all expressions without side effects gives the answer as to whether its static analysis is up to it.

Comment: @JimBalter your responses aren't particularly constructive, and I think you're missing the point of the question. I'm not looking for a magic GCC balm to solve all my problems. I was merely hoping for a way to catch obvious mistakes.

Comment: @Matthew My comments contain content; your last says nothing new or of interest.

Comment: With this technique, you could run the compiler and `grep` for when it warns about statements with no effect.  You could then grep for all `assert`s in your code.  Any mismatch is a potential side effect.  This process could be automated.  The challenge then is how to 'permanently' deal with the ambiguous cases in a safe way.

Answer (score 0):

Even if GCC could reliably detect pure computations (which would require solving the halting problem), a flag would have to have additional magical powers to notice that a non-pure computation was passed as an argument to your home-grown assert macro. An extension couldn't help either -- what exactly is it supposed to do?

The solution to your problem is

1. Hire competent developers.
2. Educate your developers about how to use asserts (among other things).
3. Do code reviews.
4. Do all testing against deliverable versions -- if asserts are off in deliverables, then assert(function_that_should_always_be_called()) is no different than simply omitting function_that_should_always_be_called(), which is a blatant bug that should be caught in testing.

Comment: I think these "solutions" are unhelpful. But more importantly, because pure computations cannot be _always_ be detected, it does not mean that eliminating _most_ pure computations is not immensely useful. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35294344/6918

Comment: What's not helpful are: a) Scare quotes b) stating a personal opinion that these solutions aren't helpful, with no rebuttal offered c) blatant strawmen --  no one said that detecting most pure computations isn't helpful d) driveby downvotes.  Bruno's answer provides a clever technique and it ought to be accepted, but it's possible to provide such answers without  being a jerk.